# Best way to validate Location data given by a user

Tags: php, html, validation, laravel

What is the best way to do this, I've used plugins before that check the input with a list of city's in United Kingdom but the list was one I had to create and thus maintain.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this in bootstrap for the users benefit and in Laravel for data integrity?

If there's not inbuilt functionality to do this what's the best alternatives.

The form I have is simple

```
<input type="text" name="location">
```

I know am getting a little cocky with things doing things for me now but using the combination of Laravel and Bootstrap I almost feel like am not working any more.

Comment: You mean you want a way to check if the city entered is valid without you maintaining a list of those cities yourself?

Comment: @Bogdan ideally, I just like to know if there are any good prebuilt ways of doing this so I don't need to hand craft one. Aswell as other peoples opinions on how they would handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to manage your validation is making validation rules in laravel with laravel custom validation

```
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules
```

Another way is to check by javascript but it isnt the best way.